# How to give different values based on a generic type parameter?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a `VertexBufferLayout` struct by following [TheChernoProject Series on openGL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD1dvfbyf6A). I've been adapting the C++ series over to Rust easily enough, but I've gotten stuck.

`VertexBufferElement` has a count, the glEnum for the `data_type` it uses and a boolean, normalized. There is a generic method called `push` which takes a u32 count that pushes a VertexBufferElement to elements Vec and updates the stride.

I can't seem to get the function to accept code for matching the type. I've attempted to use `TypeId`, `Any`, and `PhantomData` when I got an error.

```
pub fn push<T: 'a>(&mut self, count: u32) {
    let dt = TypeId::of::<T>();
    let (data_type, normalized) = if dt == TypeId::of::<i8>() {
        (gl::BYTE, false)
    } else if dt == TypeId::of::<u8>() {
        (gl::UNSIGNED_BYTE, true)
    } else if dt == TypeId::of::<i16>() {
        (gl::SHORT, false)
    } else if dt == TypeId::of::<u16>() {
        (gl::UNSIGNED_SHORT, false)
    } else if dt == TypeId::of::<i32>() {
        (gl::INT, false)
    } else if dt == TypeId::of::<u32>() {
        (gl::UNSIGNED_INT, false)
    } else if dt == TypeId::of::<f16>() {
        (gl::HALF_FLOAT, false)
    } else if dt == TypeId::of::<f32>() {
        (gl::FLOAT, false)
    } else if dt == TypeId::of::<f64>() {
        (gl::DOUBLE, false)
    } else {
        panic!("Incompatible Type")
    };
    self.elements.push(VertexBufferElement{data_type, count, normalized, _marker: PhantomData});
    self.stride += mem::size_of::<T>();
}
```

[vertex_buffer_layout.rs](https://pastebin.com/sjfEKve7)

```
    error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> opengl\examples\vertex_buffer_layout.rs:26:18
   |
25 |     pub fn push<T: 'a>(&mut self, count: u32) {
   |                 -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...
26 |         let dt = TypeId::of::<T>();
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> opengl\examples\vertex_buffer_layout.rs:26:18
   |
26 |         let dt = TypeId::of::<T>();
   |
```

At first it was 'T' may not live long enough, but it was only a generic function, and the float only dictated a number that was saved, not a type itself, so I attempted `PhantomData`. Any errors after that was me not having a clue what I'm doing, having never used `PhantomData` before, and can't find anything for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Doing what the compiler suggests works fine for me:

> help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...

```
use std::any::TypeId;

enum Type {
    Byte,
    Short,
}

fn decide<T: 'static>() -> (Type, bool) {
    let dt = TypeId::of::<T>();

    if dt == TypeId::of::<u8>() {
        (Type::Byte, false)
    } else if dt == TypeId::of::<u16>() {
        (Type::Short, true)
    } else {
        panic!("Unknown type")
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

In a future version of Rust, you can use a `match` expression to shorten it up:

```
#![feature(const_type_id)]

fn decide<T: 'static>() -> (Type, bool) {
    const ID_U8: TypeId = TypeId::of::<u8>();
    const ID_U16: TypeId = TypeId::of::<u16>();

    match TypeId::of::<T>() {
        ID_U8 => (Type::Byte, false),
        ID_U16 => (Type::Short, true),
        _ => panic!("Unknown type"),
    }
}
```

---

I would prefer to not even allow a runtime failure to be possible, however:

```
enum Type {
    Byte,
    Short,
}

trait AsType {
    fn as_type() -> (Type, bool);
}

impl AsType for u8 {
    fn as_type() -> (Type, bool) {
        (Type::Byte, false)
    }
}

impl AsType for u16 {
    fn as_type() -> (Type, bool) {
        (Type::Short, true)
    }
}

fn main() {
    u8::as_type();   // Ok
    bool::as_type(); // Error
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `as_type` found for type `bool` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:24:5
   |
24 |     bool::as_type();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `bool`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `as_type`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `AsType`
```